# Angular: Create vaiable in HTML page

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm looking to a way to declare a variable in HTML page in angular project for special needs.
In Cshtml page for Asp.net Mvc, we can do it with Razor like the way below:

```
@{    
    var var1 = "10";
    var message="";

    if(var1%2==0)
         message ="Even number";
    else
         message="Not even number";
}

<div>@message</div>
```

I know there is a way to do this in the component and make a binding after that but what i'm looking to do is to make this in the Html page like what it was done in Cshtml page.

Thanks for answer

Comment: I think you can try to write a <script> in your template and put a value there.

Comment: @devjelop Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid ,i didn't find a way to declare a variable in Html page and that was possible in cshtml page. the only to do now is to do this in component and use ngIf with binding. is there some one hwo encountered a situation like that ?

Comment: @urDMG you mean a javascript code, if yes, that is not recommanded because javascript code is repalced with typescript in angular